# Run PHP inside DNS zone Bind 10

Tags: php, linux, dns, bind

I'm using linux CentOS 6.64 with BIND 10.1.2

I have an additional zone (list.example.com) within the main DNS (example.com)

Bind (named) config file /etc/named.conf is include the zone:

```
zone "list.example.com" IN {
            type master;
    file "list-example-com.zone";
        allow-query { localhost; };
            allow-transfer { 127.0.0.1; };
    };
```

Zone file list-example-com.zone as follows:

```
$TTL 86400      ; 1 day
@               IN SOA  ns1.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. (
                        2004032201 ; serial
                        7200       ; refresh (2 hours)
                        5400       ; retry (1.5 hours)
                        1814400    ; expire (3 weeks)
                        86400      ; minimum (1 day)
                        )
                IN NS   ns1.example.com.
;
                IN A    192.168.177.22
;
; -----------------------------------------------------------------
49.30.22.66       IN A    127.0.0.3
44.63.20.10       IN A    127.0.0.2
64.42.10.5        IN A    127.0.0.2
14.3.6.8          IN A    127.0.0.3

// AND OTHER 1000S OF RECORDS LIKE THAT!
```

Let's pick one of recoded IPs as an example

The "A DNS lookup" for the IP 44.63.20.10 will be:

44.63.20.10.list.example.com and will return 127.0.0.2 from the DNS

Ok, now what i want to do is, instead of listing 1000s of IP records, i just want to run PHP file in named.conf, zone file or any other to execute some codes and return 127.0.0.2 for "A DNS" of IP 44.63.20.10

myfile.php:

```
<?php

// Just need to get the required IP (44.63.20.10) and the DNS_TYPE of the request (A, TXT,...ect) then:
// Execute some PHP codes to do some stuff (including connect to mysql database..ect)
// If the IP is TRUE, then return: (44.63.20.10     IN DNS_TYPE    X)

?>
```

I hope it clear for you.

I have my own PHP file, just need to know if it possible to do that? and if yes, then how?
Any idea please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use BIND Full function API, that allows the 'plug-in' to replace BIND's internal database function for nominated zones and from BIND.

You will need to edit the BIND source files and makefile.in and then re-build BIND including your source and header files.

To start with he API, find file db.h which is located in the directory bind-release/lib/dns/include/dns/db.h where bind-release should be replaced with the location and version number where you unpacked the source distribution e.g. /usr/src/bind/10.1.2

Here is a copy http://pastebin.com/yTN5Aq03

Answer (score 3):

With bind this is, as far as I know, not possible.

The solution that I would recommend is using [powerDNS](https://www.powerdns.com/).

PowerDNS is more flexibel, and is able to use a database. I'm using it with a MySQL database for example.
Maybe that's directly what you want, maybe it isn't. But with the flexibility of using a database, you can create a PHP script that inserts everything in the database, and checks it, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use `bind`, then something like the following solution should work.

1. Build a script to output the zone file. Can use php or just about any language to do this.
2. Once the file is generated reload bind to load the updated file.
3. If this data changes regularly, use cron to run both commands on a 5 minute interval or something appropriate to your data.